# Will there be any problem if i increase the Maximumerrorcount more than one?

Tags: ssis

I have a parent package and a child package. From the parent using the for each loop container i am calling the child package.

but i am getting a Warning and after that the package put to failure.

Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

then i increased the MaximumErrorCount to 100, then its working fine without any failure.

will there be any issues later if i am increasing the Maximumerrorcount to 100

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when executing a child package.  The package output indicated I had password issues (even though I knew I'd entered these correctly!). Turns out I had to reset the package password on the ***execute package task*** to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a well defined reason to ignore the error (which I didn't see specified) then the best course would be to investigate the actual cause of the package error.  By changing that setting you may just be suppressing a legitimate error that should be resolved.